# How can I get i2c values from a Rapsberry with Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, smbus, iio

I use an ads1115 to get values from an analogic sensor to a raspberry pi 3 but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get them from python.

I use the SMBus library to get the i2c values but I can't find how to actually get the analog 0 `AIN0` channel values. I found the i2c address for the ads1115 to be `0x48` but I can't find the address for the AIN0 channel, thus I don't have the second argument for the command `smbus.read_byte_data(0x48, ???)` and I tried some addresses like `0x00`, `0x01` but it always gives me the same values even tho the sensor values should be changing.Here's my code :

```py
from smbus import SMBus
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def main():
    i2cbus = SMBus(1)
    i2caddress = 0x48
    value = i2cbus.read_byte_data(0x48, """dont't know""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Linux kernel has the driver, use it! _drivers/iio/adc/ti-ads1015.c_

Answer (score 1):

To read digital data from ADS1115 ADC IC, you must connect analog signals to `A[0]`~`A[3]` pins of ADS1115. After ADS1115 ADC module converts the analog signal on pin `A[0]`~`A[3]` to digital form, you should read the value through the I2C interface. Check out the references section to review the case study with the ADS1115 module.

The following command call reads 2 bytes of data starting from the `0x00` register address of the I2C device whose slave address is `0x48`.

```py
# read_i2c_block_data(i2c_address, register, length, force=None)
# i2c_address -> ADS1115  I2C slave address
# register    -> ADS1115 conversion register address
# length      -> desired block length
value = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(0x48, 0x00, 2)
```

###### References

- [ADS1115 ADC Module Example with SMBus](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/ADS1115/tree/master/Python)
- [ADS1115 Python Driver](https://github.com/ncdcommunity/Raspberry_Pi_ADS1115_16Bit_4Channel_ADC_Python_Library/blob/master/ADS1115.py)

Comment: Linux kernel has already the driver.

Comment: @0andriy The kernel drivers are not easy to access from python. The use of a python library makes things much easier.

Comment: @PMF, `libiio` has Python bindings, what stops you to use it? https://analogdevicesinc.github.io/libiio/v0.20/python/index.html (I believe this is available in your distro, e.g. Debian _python3-libiio/unstable,unstable 0.23-2 all Python bindings for libiio_) Besides the fact that with it you may access to 500+ drivers in the kernel at once.

Comment: @0andriy _That_ is a possible approach. I was referring to writing the bindings yourself. Whether the bindings internally use a kernel driver or do their own thing (just on top of a raw i2c device) is irrelevant for the user, but one should use a binding if it exists.

Comment: @PMF, there are a lot of disadvantages by **not** using in-kernel drivers, one of which is what we may clearly see in this question. I guess at the end of the day we are on the same page.